# Unable to open Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am unable to open Outlook 2010 on my Windows 7 computer. Outlook displays the splash screen but hangs at "Loading profile".  I have tried running it in Safe Mode, but it still won't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: More details are needed to help you with this.  Are you receiving an error?  What is the behavior when you try to open it?

Comment: Hello Wes thanks for replying. it starts up and gets stuck at 'loading profile'. i've trying opening in safe mode but it doesn't work. it has worked in the past, like the day before, and now does not respond at all.

Comment: I don't want to be *that guy* but googling it suggests a bunch of possible solutions. https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=outlook+stuck+loading+profile .

Comment: Well, yes, I did look. No answers went beyond opening in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across similar problems in the past. You may be able to repair the Microsoft Office installation files:

- Click Start, type '*Programs and Features*' and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Find the entry for **Microsoft Office**. it should look something like this:
  [image: Microsoft Office Professional Plus in Programs and Features]
- Right-click the entry, and click '*Change*'
- On the first window that pops up, select '*Repair*' and click 'Continue'
- Follow any other prompts
- Restart your PC

Comment: I appreciate your help - unfortunately, it did not fix my problem. should i uninstall and reinstall? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I found a link to MS to download Microsoft Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 1.2 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36852

Comment: This at least told me that the problem was a Bluetooth add-in.  Clicking on the MS Fix It button unfortunately did not work since apparently the expected software was not found. no details. there is manual option but it sounds too scary, as in "Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These problems might require that you reinstall the operating system."

Comment: @Barbara - If it is an add-on, can you disable it when running in Outlook's safe mode? (Hold Ctrl when starting Outlook). The addins should be under File->Options->Add-ins. Otherwise, you can try reinstalling Office entirely

Comment: I can't open in Safe mode. I'll try your other suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Today my Outlook suddenly started working without me doing anything else other than clicking on the icon. I went to File/Options to disable the bluetooth add-in that was apparently causing the problem but found it already disabled. so it is a mystery - to me anyway.